# Putting subsites outside of the sites directory

Tags: 7, subsites

When number of subsites increase, is there a way to put subsites in a directory outside of *sites* directory or even outside of drupal base directory, like */var* ?

Are *symlinks* the only solution?

Answer (score 2):

The location of subsites is hard-wired in function [conf_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_settings_initialize/7).